# Laravel Migration Error

Tags: mysql, laravel

```
root@jack:/var/www/xxx.com# php artisan migrate

Migration table created successfully.

[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1114 The table 'users' is full (SQL: alter
table `users` add unique users_email_unique(`email`))

[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1114 The table 'users' is full
```

just installed fresh laravel 5, i got error when run migration it say table users is full, i already searching in google and add to my.cnf

```
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_file_format = barracuda
```

then remove all database and restore again..

any idea for this error?

thank you

Comment: Have you restarted MySQL after you have changed my.cnf?

Comment: offcourse i restart mysql and still got error

Comment: How did you resolve this problem?